# Editing a Bound Gridview Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm implementing an "edit" feature on my Gridview bound to my "books" table. I'm receiving an error on RowEditingEvent wasn't handled. I don't understand where I'm going wrong or if I'm missing a reference somewhere but it seems to me that everything is handled.

```
public partial class AddEdit_Text_Books : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select  * from textBooks   ";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HUTDMSConnectionString"].ToString()))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))


                adapter.Fill(dt);
            ViewState["allBooks"] = dt;
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["allBooks"] as DataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        string name = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string country = (row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        DataTable dt = ViewState["allBooks"] as DataTable;

        ViewState["allBooks"] = dt;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }

    protected void OnCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
```

}

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BookID"  Width="1482px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="thirteenISBN" HeaderText="thirteenISBN" SortExpression="thirteenISBN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseID" HeaderText="CourseID" SortExpression="CourseID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookTitle" HeaderText="BookTitle" SortExpression="BookTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ancillary" HeaderText="Ancillary" SortExpression="Ancillary" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookActive" HeaderText="BookActive" SortExpression="BookActive" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActiveDate" HeaderText="ActiveDate" SortExpression="ActiveDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InactiveDate" HeaderText="InactiveDate" SortExpression="InactiveDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" SortExpression="Author" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookID" HeaderText="BookID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BookID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="eISBN" HeaderText="eISBN" SortExpression="eISBN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ebookAvailable" HeaderText="ebookAvailable" SortExpression="ebookAvailable" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorISBN" HeaderText="VendorISBN" SortExpression="VendorISBN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="tenISBN" HeaderText="tenISBN" SortExpression="tenISBN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EditionAndDate" HeaderText="EditionAndDate" SortExpression="EditionAndDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher" HeaderText="Publisher" SortExpression="Publisher" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Imprint" HeaderText="Imprint" SortExpression="Imprint" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" />
        <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HUTDMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [thirteenISBN], [CourseID], [BookTitle], [Ancillary], [BookActive], [ActiveDate], [InactiveDate], [Author], [BookID], [Notes], [eISBN], [ebookAvailable], [VendorISBN], [tenISBN], [EditionAndDate], [Publisher], [Imprint] FROM [textBooks]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image: Stack Trace Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not registered onediting event in gridview definition.
Add `OnRowEditing ="OnRowEditing"` in below gridview definition.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BookID"  Width="1482px" 
CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowEditing ="OnRowEditing">
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, 1 more quick question maybe you could help with, After editing and clicking the update button, it doesnt save, updates to my database? am I missing some sort of update table in my OnUpdate Method

Comment: You have to write code to update the values in database in onupdate method. You will easily get the code sample on searching. You will need to execute sql query of update the similar way you have used the sql query to select the data from database.